# Maximum entropy distribution given second order marginals

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

Let $p(x,y,z)$ be a probability distribution over 3 variables (suppose them discrete, but it shouldn't matter). I know that the distribution with maximal entropy which preserves the first order marginals $p(x),p(y),p(z)$ is simply the product $p(x)p(y)p(z)$.

What is instead the distribution with maximal entropy which preserves these marginals: $p(x,y),p(x,z),p(y,z)$? Or if there is no closed form, can I define it implicitly?

Thanks.

Comment: My intuition tells me you will only be able to preserve one of $p(x,y)$, $p(x,z)$ or $p(y,z)$ at a time unless you take the full joint probability.

Comment: Why? Just take a lower entropy.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, could you give an example?

Comment: There always exist a distribution which has all the same double marginals, namely the original $p$. And possibly some other...among which we take the one with the highest entropy. If it were impossible to find others, it would mean that the double marginals determine $p$ uniquely, which is absurd.

Comment: Why is it absurd that all three double marginals *taken together* uniquely define $p$? I'm trying to find an example where that is not the case but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: Three binary variables $x,y,z$, take $p=1/4(\delta_{000}+\delta_{011}+\delta_{101}+\delta_{110})$. where $\delta_{xyz}$ is a peak at the position $xyz$. Visually, it is the 3D equivalent of "chess". It's easy to see that the double marginals are all constant.

Comment: Oh man, not enough coffee today obviously. I've seen exactly this example in 2D before.

Comment: In this case a constant 1/8 distribution is the max entropy solution...but I have no clue in the general case!